# Karate: simplest way to validate value of array json response should not be empty

Tags: arrays, karate, notnull

```
response= [
{
"id": "123",
"name: "user1",
"location": "USA"
},
{
"id": "133",
"name: "user2",
"location": "CANADA"
},
{
"id": "",
"name": "user3",
"location": "INDIA"
}
]
```

I am trying to validate the above json array using the schema and want to validate that values of my keys should not be empty or blank.

I am using the below code:

```
* def schema = {"id": "#notnull", "name": "#notnull", "location": "#notnull"}
* match each response contains schema
```

But even though my response has "id":"" -- id is empty/blank in the 3rd index in json array. Still I get a pass in my scenario.
Is this the correct way or is there any other way to handle empty values in schema for a json array response.

Your help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps `#present` would help

Comment: I tried with #present too and still it was not giving me any failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally we should have `#notblank` but we don't because it is so rare.

Do this instead:

```
* match each response contains { id: "#? _ != ''" }
```